# AC analysis of voltage divider CE amplifier - how are non-parallel resistors treated as parallel?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, ac, analysis

[image]

The textbook I'm reading (*Electronics for Guitarists* by Denton J. Dailey) has this to say about the AC equivalent of the circuit:

> The power supply voltage source VCC provides a low resistance path to
> ground for signals. This effectively places RC in parallel with RL. This
> gives us RC'=RC||RL. Also, an AC input signal “sees” two paths to
> ground via R1and R2, therefore the equivalent resistance from base to
> ground is RB'=R1||R2

Neither of these points make much sense to me. What properties of a power supply make it provide a low-resistance path for AC signals, and even then, how does that translate to an equivalent load resistance RC||RL when the resistors are not in fact parallel with each other?

Similarly, what is meant by the AC signal "seeing" R1 as a path to ground? I thought maybe this was something to do with the change in current direction, but the signal is biased to always be positive.

Comment: Ideal power supplies don't change voltage when current is taken out (or put in) so they have zero output impedance. Hence, for AC purposes, they are grounds.

Comment: Oh! Somehow I went my entire EE undergrad without realizing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What properties of a power supply make it provide a low-resistance path for AC signals

In AC analysis you treat the DC power supply as a short.

This is justified by the rule of superposition.